# I have no idea what's wrong with my TensorFlow program

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd appreciate it very much if anyone could give me pointers on what I need to fix. I'm new to TensorFlow and I have no idea what is going wrong.

The code:

```
from PIL import ImageFont, Image, ImageDraw
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,48,48,1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,26])

def initW(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.01))

w1 = initW([5,5,1,32])
w2 = initW([5,5,32,64])
w3 = initW([64*12*12,26])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

saver = tf.train.Saver()

def model(x,w1,w2,w3,keep_prob):
    l1c = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(x, w1, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = "SAME"))
    l1p = tf.nn.max_pool(l1c, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = "SAME")
    l2c = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(l1p, w2, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = "SAME"))
    l2p = tf.nn.max_pool(l2c, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")
    l2r = tf.reshape(l2p,[-1,64*12*12])
    l2d = tf.nn.dropout(l2r, keep_prob)
    l3f = tf.matmul(l2d,w3)

    return l3f

model = model(x,w1,w2,w3,keep_prob)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y, logits = model))

op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.000002).minimize(cost)

def imgData(char):
    img = Image.new("L", (48, 48), color=255)
    f = ImageFont.truetype("Arial.ttf", 50)
    ImageDraw.Draw(img).text((25 - f.getsize("W")[0] / 2, 0), "W", font=f)
    return np.reshape(img.getdata(),[48,48,1])

def oneHot(C,reshape=False):
    arr = [0] * 26
    arr[charToInt(C)] = 1
    if reshape:
        return np.reshape(arr,[1,26])
    else:
        return arr

def charToInt(C):
    return ord(C) - ord("A")

def accuracy():
    alphabet = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    testSet = np.array([imgData(C) for C in alphabet])
    testLabels = np.array([oneHot(C) for C in alphabet])
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(model,1),tf.argmax(y,1)),tf.float32))
    print (sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:testSet,y:testLabels,keep_prob:1.0}))

def predict(char):
    probabilities = sess.run(model, feed_dict= {x:[imgData(char)], keep_prob: 0.5})[0]
    for n in range(26):
        print (chr(ord("A") + n) + ": " + "{0:.2f}".format(probabilities[n]))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    alphabet = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    random.shuffle(alphabet)

    train = True
    if train:
        for n in range(20):
            for C in alphabet:
                sess.run(op, feed_dict = {
                    x: [imgData(C)],
                    y: oneHot(C,reshape=True),
                    keep_prob: 0.5
                })
            print("cost: " + str(sess.run(cost,feed_dict={
                x:[imgData(C)],
                y:oneHot(C,reshape=True),
                keep_prob: 1.0
            })))
            saver.save(sess,"./model")

    else:
        saver.restore(sess,"./model")
        accuracy()
        # predict("B")
```

This is a simple convolutional neural network program that takes an image of an uppercase letter and outputs the predicted character. `x` is the input tensor for the 48x48 image generated by `imgData(char)`, and `y` is the output to represent an uppercase character.

The cnn model is found inside `model(x,w1,w2,w3,keep_prob)`.
Despite trying various numbers for the learning rate and epoch, the cost always converges to around 3.3.

`accuracy()` prints out the measured accuracy of the model using a test set. It always says 0.0384615. I want `predict()` to show what probabilities of a given image to be various characters, but right now it is giving all kinds of weird numbers.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `imgData` method has a typo: you should write out `char` instead of `W` if I understand correctly (see documentation of [ImageDraw.draw.text](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm#tag-ImageDraw.Draw.text)). Otherwise, your golden label will be always the character of `W`. That's why you always get an accuracy of 0.0384 which is 1/26, i.e. you only learn to recognize one of the 26 characters (which is expected, because you never provide labels for other characters other than `W`).

```
def imgData(char):
    img = Image.new("L", (48, 48), color=255)
    f = ImageFont.truetype("/tmp/arial.ttf", 50)
    ImageDraw.Draw(img).text((25 - f.getsize("W")[0] / 2, 0), char, font=f)
    return np.reshape(img.getdata(),[48,48,1])
```

I also increase your learning rate by 10x. Then the model overfits in ~10 iterations:

```
0, cost: 4.96586 accu 0.0769231
1, cost: 5.01186 accu 0.115385
2, cost: 3.9491 accu 0.230769
3, cost: 2.56 accu 0.384615
4, cost: 1.99173 accu 0.423077
5, cost: 2.51248 accu 0.576923
6, cost: 2.19388 accu 0.730769
7, cost: 3.79979 accu 0.769231
8, cost: 2.25762 accu 0.807692
9, cost: 1.27227 accu 0.884615
10, cost: 0.964877 accu 0.884615
11, cost: 2.15709 accu 0.923077
12, cost: 0.482007 accu 0.961538 
13, cost: 0.733133 accu 1.0
```

Comment: Ah, shoot, that is a big fail on my part :P Thank you!

Comment: np. BTW, your way of building your training data on the fly is interesting! If you could add some noise that would be more interesting.

Comment: Hey, good idea with adding noise. I'm also thinking of transformations and using different fonts.